# Error when importing framework objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks, mac-frameworks

I am trying to add TCMPortMapper (http://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/)

I have linked the framework in the build phases and tried to run the example code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <TCMPortMapper/TCMPortMapper.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])

{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    TCMPortMapper *pm = [TCMPortMapper sharedInstance];
    [pm addPortMapping:
    [TCMPortMapping portMappingWithLocalPort:13478 
                         desiredExternalPort:4321 
                           transportProtocol:TCMPortMappingTransportProtocolTCP
                                    userInfo:nil]];
    [pm start];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

but I get the error :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/TCMPortMapper.framework/TCMPortMapper, missing          required     
architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TCMPortMapper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TCMPortMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Im guessing it has something to do with the framework, not me. But I've spent a lot of time googling
and haven't turned up much except it might be something with 32 and 64 bit modes.

Any help would be very much appreciated because I've been stuck on this for 3 days.

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the binary release of TCPPortMapper? It doesn't have x86_64 arch executable.

```
$ file TCMPortMapper.framework/TCMPortMapper
TCMPortMapper.framework/TCMPortMapper: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
TCMPortMapper.framework/TCMPortMapper (for architecture ppc):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
TCMPortMapper.framework/TCMPortMapper (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

Add GCC "-m32" or "-arch i386" option to CFLAGS and LDFLAGS, or build TCPPortMapper yourself for x86_64 arch.

Comment: Chances are OP is already building both i386 and x86_64. OP could remove the x86_64 architecture from the build settings to force their machine to run the i386 architecture, but building an i386/x86_64 universal version of the framework would be the better solution.

Comment: Also set the deployment target to 10.5 or 10.4 would be better.